# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Screen' and indentation error

Tags: python, terminal, turtle-graphics

I'm learning Turtle class for Python. While running `shp.py` file in terminal I got multiple errors:

[image]

What is going wrong?

```
import turtle as myTurtle

def draw_shape():

window = myTurtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("yellow")

brack = myTurtle.Turtle()
brack.shape("turtle")
brack.speed(2)
c = 1
while c < 5:
    brack.forward(100)
    brack.right(90)
    c = c+1

rosy = myTurtle.Turtle()
rosy.shape("arrow")
rosy.color("blue")
rosy.circle(100)

matt = myTurtle.Turtle()
matt.shape("circle")
i = 1
while i < 4:
    matt.forward(320)   
    matt.left(120)
i = i+1

window.exitonclick()

draw_shape()
```

Comment: Your script is importing itself. Give it a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your script is importing itself. A simple change to the file name can fix this.

```
Go to My Documents -> Locate your file -> Right click on it -> Click Rename -> Enter a new name like myTurtle.py
```

Comment: @IshankChauhan The second method did not work but I am unable to reproduce your problem if you rename your file.